# import qgis.core in Python

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I am trying to use QGIS3.4 by using Emacs (elpy) on Mac OS Mojava. I checked following sources:

1. https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/pdf/en/QGIS-3.4-PyQGISDeveloperCookbook-en.pdf
2. http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Error-importing-qgis-in-python-td4141685.html
3. [Calling QGIS from MacOS python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123251/calling-qgis-from-macos-python)

Then, I use the following code:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append('/Applications/QGIS3.4.app/Contents/Resources/python/')
sys.path.append('/Applications/QGIS3.4.app/Contents/Resources/python/plugins')
sys.path.append('/Applications/QGIS3.4.app/Contents/MacOS/lib')
import qgis.core
```

But, I got the following result.

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Applications/QGIS3.4.app/Contents/Resources/python/qgis/_core.so, 2): Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Frameworks/qgis_core.framework/qgis_core
  Referenced from: /Applications/QGIS3.4.app/Contents/Resources/python/qgis/_core.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Could you help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Hi, unfortunately i don't have the answer, but i'm having the same troubles. Wondering if you found a solution for this?

Comment: I don't have an answer yet. But, I think this problem is related to multiple versions of python on my computer. So I tried to uninstall my original python. If so, I can see some progress. But, it does not work still.